# Prevent RestTemplate from reordering parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to use the `RestTemplate` to send a request with the following format:
`http://host:port/action?loc=x,y&t=z&loc=x1,y1&t=z1...`

What's important is that the ordering of parameters matters. In this case the each `t` refers to location previous `loc`.

No matter how I try to set the parameters for the `RestTemplate` the resulting request parameters get reordered. All `loc` parameters appear before all `t` like this: `http://host:port/action?loc=x,y&loc=x1,y1&loc=...&t=z1&t=z2&t=...`

Is there any way to prevent `RestTemplate` from reordering the request parameters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple parameters with the same name, in your case multiple instances of `loc` - it is treated as an array, that's why they're all coupled together.